# Display search result page on back

Tags: php, mysql, html, codeigniter

I am developing a website in php (I am using codeigniter). On search by user I need to display list of products. Search result should give small description about the each product. Once the user clicks on more anchor I need to give full description about the product. Once user clicks back I need to be back to the search result page. I have used pagination. Any suggestion on how to carry out this task. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, this sounds like a job for our good friend Javascript. But not that much - simple history trick would be sufficient in my opinion. Resource:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/history.shtml

Example:

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-3)">Go back 3 pages</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for our good friend Javascript. You could do this with a modal window that retrieves a page (such as /product/id/full_description) and displays the full description.

There are many modal window scripts out there that can do this. I am using jQuery and one called SimpleModal (http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) and it works well. I am using this since I am already using jQuery for many other things.

Here are some other examples:

- http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex8/dhtmlwindow/dhtmlmodal.htm
- http://okonet.ru/projects/modalbox/index.html
- http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/
- http://orangoo.com/labs/GreyBox/
- http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/